# Loading jquery in MVC 4.0 master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In the `<head>` section of my _Layout.cshtml(master page) file I have the following reference to minified jQuery:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After adding this line I can now use jQuery in everyone of my pages which reference the master page which is great.What I would like to know is how often is the loading of the jQuery file performed?Will it be done everytime a page is loaded or only once when the first page of the website is loaded in the browser?

Comment: As you are using MVC, you should also use bundles to improve performance across multiple JS scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file will be loaded in to the browsers' cache upon first load. For every subsequent request it will be read from the cache to reduce bandwidth requirements and improve speed.

If you really want to improve performance, you can load jQuery.js from a global CDN, such as Google, which has the advantage of being fast, and due to it's widespread use it's highly likely that someone already has jQuery in their cache from this location.

I would also suggest using a newer version of jQuery as 1.8.2 is quite old now. If you need legacy browser support (IE9 and lower), use 1.11:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you can use the smaller and more efficient 2.x:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For multiple JS files, *bundling* "local" files is more efficient than using a CDN, as the number of JS files is usually the bottleneck. Again this does depend on the file, version and how commonly used it is on the user's browser.

Comment: Do you know if this behaviour will be the same when accessing a website on an iPad using Safari?

Comment: @Denis yes, it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, create a bundles for your javascript files
in App_Start\BundleConfig.cs file, add bellow code.
it will load all jquery- prefixed files where the remainder is a version number
e.g. **jquery-1.10.2.js**

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

or

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/*.js"));
```

this will load all the .js files from scripts folder.

To load above bundle, go to your _Layour.cshtml (your master page) and render as bellow

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

**UPDATE**

Same way you can create bundle/minification for your custom javascript file.

set this flag true in your BundleConfig.cs file for minification of javascript files

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: Actually that first one will only load `jquery-` prefixed files *where the remainder is a version number*. e.g. it will *not* load jquery-ui-*.js

Comment: So if I do it this way can i add all the other javascript files that I'm using in the web application and they will also be loaded only once?

Comment: Nope, so what it will do is, for the first time, it will do minification of your javascript and creates a bundle (that will very much lower in size), and then whenever required it will return minified js bundle.

Comment: Do i need to create minified files for everyone of my scripts?Or will mvc automatically minify my scripts?

Comment: You need to true " enableOptimization= true " flag, MVC will do rest,
detailed explanation on how performance improved on bundling and minification check bellow link.

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification